# iPhone XML Parsing problem

Tags: iphone, xml, ios4, xml-parsing

I am new to iPhone dev and I am trying to parse this link and put it on my tableview, however when my tableview shows up, the titles do not show up in the rows. What I am doing wrong here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"RSS Feeds";

rssList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.rpg.net/index.xml"];
NSLog(@"%@",URLString);



NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];


NSXMLParser *firstParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[firstParser setDelegate:self];
[firstParser parse];

[URLString release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if ([elementName compare:@"item"] == NSOrderedSame) {

[rssList addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"],@"title",
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"link"],@"link",
nil]];

}
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to return a cell formatted with elements from `rssList`?

Comment: first check whether the parsing is working or not

Answer (score 0):

use this for xml parsing from a rss feed.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [stories count];
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
[cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];

return cell;
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Navigation logic

 int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

 NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];

 // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
 storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
 storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
 storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

 NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
 // open in Safari
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
  }


  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
  }

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if ([stories count] == 0) {
    NSString * path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
}

cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     }

   - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   }




   - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{    
NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");

   }

   - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
     {  
stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
   NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

// here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
// this may be necessary only for the toolchain
rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

// Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
[rssParser setDelegate:self];

// Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

[rssParser parse];

  }

   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
   }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{          
//NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    // clear out our story item caches...
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

     }

   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
//NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];

    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
}

    }

   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
//NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
// save the characters for the current item...
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [currentTitle appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [currentLink appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
    [currentSummary appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
    [currentDate appendString:string];
}

     }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

NSLog(@"all done!");
NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
[newsTable reloadData];
    }





  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
// Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
     }


   - (void)dealloc {

[currentElement release];
[rssParser release];
[stories release];
[item release];
[currentTitle release];
[currentDate release];
[currentSummary release];
[currentLink release];

[super dealloc];
     }
```

Comment: -1 Bad answer. You shouldn't just dump code in here with no explanation, and there's a lot of differently-named variables already used by the OP. You need to be more concise and provide only the two or three required functions to implement. If you really want to write the code yourself, at least have the courtesy to name the variables the same way the OP does. Also, please indent your code block with 4 spaces on every line so it formats properly.